# DRF permission not taking effect

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The following permission is not taking effect `IsOwnerOrReadOnly` I can don't understand why:

```
class PermissionMixin(object):
    """
    API Permission Mixin.
    Permission checks authentication information in the request.user and request.auth
    properties to determine if the incoming request should be permitted.
    """

    permission_classes = [Or(permissions.IsAdminUser, TokenHasReadWriteScope), And (IsOwnerOrReadOnly)]
```

I want IsAdminUser or TokenHasReadWriteScope user to be permitted, but always check they are the owner `IsOwnerOrReadOnly`.

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions are only allowed to the owner of object.
        return obj.user == request.user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the right way to set the permission is:

```
permission_classes = [And(Or(permissions.IsAdminUser, TokenHasReadWriteScope), IsOwnerOrReadOnly)]
```

Tell me if this works.

Comment: Hi thank you for the response. I tested your code and it still does not run the IsOwnerOrReadOnly function. I added a print statement to the class and it just does not run. admin and token do however. any more ideas? :)

Comment: it appears you answer does work!!!! the issues was with the order i added the mixin to the view. thank you for your answer.